# require all model of mongoose in express app.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

In my app.js of express app, I always have to include model every time I created a model

```
require('./models/Users')
require('./models/Projects')
```

Is there a way to avoid this? something like `require('./models/*)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using [glob](https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob) to get all file in models path

```
var glob = require( 'glob' )
  , path = require( 'path' );

glob.sync( './models/**/*.js' ).forEach( function( file ) {
  require( path.resolve( file ) );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Using native `nodejs`, You can read the `directory` and load/require modules `dynamically`.

```
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");
const models = fs.readdirSync("./models/");
models.forEach((dir) => {
  if (fs.statSync(dir).isFile) require(path.join("./models/", dir));
});
```

Util:

```
const getModels = (dir) => {
  return fs
    .readdirSync(dir)
    .filter((file) => fs.statSync(file).isFile)
    .map((file) => require(path.join("./models/", file)));
};
module.exports ={getModels}
```

**// How to use**

```
const models = getModels("./models/")
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a Separate file which will include all the exported module file and just export on objects and use it whenever required,